# Is this a fleur-de-lis hood ornament, or something else?

Tags: part-identification

I came across this interesting piece:

[image: An interesting piece]

Now, I'm not sure it is a hood ornament, but I would like to know *what* it is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like a fleur de lys...

Comment: I think you may have stolen King Kahuka's tribal feather-thingy...

Comment: @Coyote I was trying to think of something to liken it to. It kind of looks like the top half of a fleur-de-lis, if you squint your eyes.

Comment: LOL, ok. PeterDC seems to be right... It's a feather ornament, it doesn't look like the ones on medieval helmets so it might be one of the tribal ones.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like a minifigure headgear accessory, specifically a [feathered headdress plume (no. 6029b)](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=6029b):

[image]

It's appeared in [a number of sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6029b&in=S), most with pirate, castle, or western themes and sometimes as an extra part. It's sometimes packaged in a ["Plume Wheel"](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=6029c01) (i.e. still in a circular runner with some [cattle horns](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=6029a)), and is typically used for [islander minifigs](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6029b&in=M):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the identification. I now completely remember these from the Lego Racers game.